# Is there any randomness involved in the algorithm to generate QR codes

Tags: javascript, code-generation, qr-code

Will the same data always generate the same QR code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm to generate QR codes does not include any randomness as it is simply a method for representing data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no randomness in QR Codes.

Anyway, there are some parameters that should change the output you get for the same data:

- Different levels of error correction,
- Different encoding,
- …

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) on wkipedia should answer to many of the questions you can ask about QR Codes.